# Getting Vlookup to pull item for data validation list and calculate price

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, data-analysis

Working through some data set problems for an analytics class and I have everything figured out but one.

We're supposed to allow a data validation list (Order #s) provide some information to us from a larger data set (Item Description, Supplier, Discount Price, Shipment Days). The one I'm stuck on is the discount date.

I have the vlookup for the calculation figured out: =VLOOKUP(I4, $L$12:$M$15, 2, 1)*G4 with a small table I created of the months and discounts applicable. What I can't figure out is how to nest that within another VLOOKUP (or a different route) to get get it to reference the data validation list. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Surely you need the exact match? which means the last argument is 0 not 1.

Comment: When you say a Data Validation list do you mean the Excel data validation function (Data ribbon > Data Tools > Data Validation) or a list that you're validating your look ups against (so just some data in a range of cells).